# Difference between the Vertical and Angled grips?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I haven't really noticed the difference between either of the grips when playing the game. What does each one do to effect the weapon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [forum post](http://forums.playbattlegrounds.com/topic/3349-vertical-grip-vs-angled-grip/) the:

> Vertical does horz/vert recoil in a larger percentage then the angled but the angled lets you ADS faster while still giving small vert/horizontal recoil reduction.

This information seems to have come from one of the [dev streams](https://www.twitch.tv/fragout_smk)<sup>(Twitch link seems to be dead)</sup> and looks to be confirmed by additional forum members. Not sure how exactly accurate it is though.

Comment: What means ADS ?

Comment: @Hybris95 "Aim(ing) Down Sights"